# Remove strong name from assembly while de serialize using regular expressions

Tags: c#, regex, serialization, strongname

Wanted to share a way I found to remove strong name from assembly name.
I used it for de serialize but I assume it can be used for other things too.

```
    private Regex _assemRegex = new Regex("(?<assembly>^.*?),.*");
    Regex reg = new Regex("(?<type>.*?), PublicKeyToken(=.*?)](?<end>.*)");
    //assume that all replacement types are in the same assembly with TypeReplacer
    static readonly string assembly2Use = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName;

    public override Type BindToType(string assemblyName, string typeName)
    {
        // remove strong name from assembly
        Match match = _assemRegex.Match(assemblyName);
        if (match.Success)
        {
            assemblyName = match.Groups["assembly"].Value;
        }

        // remove strong name from any generic collections as many time as needed
        match = reg.Match(typeName);
        string typeWithoutSN = typeName;
        while (match.Success)
        {
            typeWithoutSN = string.Format("{0}]{1}",
            match.Groups["type"].Value,
            match.Groups["end"].Value);
            match = reg.Match(typeWithoutSN);
        }

        // replace assembly name with the simple assembly
        // name - strip the strong name
        string type = string.Format("{0}, {1}", typeWithoutSN,
        assemblyName);

        // The following line of code returns the type.
        return Type.GetType(type);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing, maybe you could put the code as an answer to this question, and accept it later (there is a time limit) That way people wont seek to answer this post.

Comment: good comment gideon, I will do it later (can't at the moment)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As requested the code is mark as answer:

```
private Regex _assemRegex = new Regex("(?<assembly>^.*?),.*");
Regex reg = new Regex("(?<type>.*?), PublicKeyToken(=.*?)](?<end>.*)");
//assume that all replacement types are in the same assembly with TypeReplacer
static readonly string assembly2Use = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName;

public override Type BindToType(string assemblyName, string typeName)
{
    // remove strong name from assembly
    Match match = _assemRegex.Match(assemblyName);
    if (match.Success)
    {
        assemblyName = match.Groups["assembly"].Value;
    }

    // remove strong name from any generic collections as many time as needed
    match = reg.Match(typeName);
    string typeWithoutSN = typeName;
    while (match.Success)
    {
        typeWithoutSN = string.Format("{0}]{1}",
        match.Groups["type"].Value,
        match.Groups["end"].Value);
        match = reg.Match(typeWithoutSN);
    }

    // replace assembly name with the simple assembly
    // name - strip the strong name
    string type = string.Format("{0}, {1}", typeWithoutSN,
    assemblyName);

    // The following line of code returns the type.
    return Type.GetType(type);
}
```

Comment: Would I run this code in my running application that I want the Strong Name removed from? Do you have a few examples of how to call this? For example, would I call it like this : `BindToType("project1.exe", "System.Windows.Form");`?

Comment: You should override the serializatonbinder class